# How can i provide a user input and an if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

i am making a something on the raspberry pi that will give you stock prices. here is the code:

```
import ystockquote
tickerSymbol = 'ADSK'
allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)
print tickerSymbol + " Price = " + allInfo["price"]
```

I first had to download ystockquote on the pi to get the stockquotes from yahoo finance. The tickerSymbol is where you type in the company's name(abbreviation, ADSK is autodesk). what i want to do is manually type in the company abbreviation and then it will provide the price. i have tried things that i thought would work. not the experienced though with python than i am with c++.

Comment: use `raw_input()`(Python 2.x) or `input()` (Python3.x) to get input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Use `raw_input()` for Python 2.x and `input()` for Python 3.x

Demo:

```
>>> user_input = raw_input("Enter value:")
Enter value:test
>>> print user_input
test
>>>
```

---

Use **break** statement if you want to get User Input in any loop to come out from the loop.

Demo

```
>>> while True:
...    user_input = raw_input("Enter value:")
...    if user_input.lower()=="no":
...         print "break while loop"
...         break
...    print "User Value:", user_input
... 
Enter value:test
User Value: test
Enter value:test1
User Value: test1
Enter value:No
break while loop
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
while True:
    tickerSymbol = raw_input('Enter a stock symbol: ')
    allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)
    print tickerSymbol + " Price = " + allInfo["price"]
```

Encapsulating this in a `while True:` loop will allow the user to continue to get new quotes without having to restart the program.

Also as stated above use `raw_input()` for 2.x and `input()` for 3+